# Give permissions for hdfs target directory using JAVA API

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have to give the permisions for hdfs target directory whenever I put the data into hdfs by using JAVA API. I have tried the following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;`enter code here`
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission;
import org.apache.hadoop.thriftfs.api.IOException;

public class MovetoHdfs {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        MovetoHdfs m=new MovetoHdfs();
        Configuration conf1=new Configuration();
        //Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Enter the input path");
        String inp=br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter output path");

        String opt=br.readLine();

        //m.moveFile(conf1,inp,opt);

        conf1.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://10.2.152.113:8020");
        conf1.set("dfs.permissions.enabled", "false");
        conf1.set("dfs.permissions", "false");

        FileSystem fs= FileSystem.get(conf1);
        m.moveFile(fs,inp,opt);
    }

    public void moveFile(Configuration conf,final String inputFile, final String outputFile) throws Exception {

        FileSystem fs=null;
        conf=new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://10.2.152.113:8020");
        conf.set("dfs.permissions.enabled", "false");
        conf.set("dfs.permissions", "false");
        Path src=new Path(inputFile);

        Path dest=new Path(outputFile);

        fs=FileSystem.get(conf);
        //fs.setPermission(dest, fp);
        fs.moveFromLocalFile(src, dest);
        fs.close();

    }

    public void moveFile(final String inputFile, final String outputFile) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf;

        conf=new Configuration();

        Path src=new Path(inputFile);

        Path dest=new Path(outputFile);

        FileSystem dfs=FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://10.2.152.113:8020"),conf);
        conf.set("dfs.permissions.enabled", "false");
        conf.set("dfs.permissions", "false");
        dfs.moveFromLocalFile(src, dest);
        dfs.close();
    }
}
```

I got the following error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=Srinivas.budida, access=WRITE, inode="/user/hdfs/Test":root:hadoop:-rw-r--r--
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPathAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:551)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.create(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1603)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1903)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1871)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.moveFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1858)
    at com.solix.bigdata.MovetoHdfs.moveFile(MovetoHdfs.java:105)
    at com.solix.bigdata.MovetoHdfs.main(MovetoHdfs.java:46)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=Srinivas.budida, access=WRITE, inode="/user/hdfs/Test":root:hadoop:-rw-r--r--
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPathAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:551)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.create(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1599)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code snippet. its a simple example for creating directory on hdfs. Use the dfs object.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;

import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class testinghdfs {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException 

{ 
try{
UserGroupInformation ugi
    = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("hdfs");

  ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {

 public Void run() throws Exception {

   Configuration config = new Configuration();
   config.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
   config.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

   config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", 
           org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
       config.set("fs.file.impl",org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
 FileSystem dfs = FileSystem.get(config);

  String dirName = "TestDirectory";
  System.out.println(dfs.getWorkingDirectory() +" this is from /n/n");
  Path src = new Path(dfs.getWorkingDirectory()+"/"+dirName);
  // dfs.mkdirs(src); 

    dfs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("/home/inputs/TMPAAA022389.RPT"), new Path("/user/hdfs/test"));



  return null;
 }
});
}
catch(Exception e){}
 }}
```

Comment: Hi sravan,thank you for your reply,above code is creating directory in hdfs, but my question is i already created one directory in hdfs and move the data from local to hdfs by using java api, so whenever i moving the data it showing error permission is denied, so is there any method for giving the permissions for target directory whenever moving the data

Comment: i updated answer. you already created  hdfs on file system. so  create a remote user on that directory in code.run it. let me know any issues

Comment: Hi Sravan,in above code it is creating the new user in and then we are  creating the directory in that user,but I don't want to create the new user,just I want become as root(I mean to change the current user to root for copying  that particular file) and copy that file .Is it possible?

Comment: Hi Sravan,in above code it is creating the new user in and then we are creating the directory in that user,but I don't want to create the new user,just I want become as root(I mean to change the current user to root for copying that particular file) and copy that file .Is it possible? It is some urgent for our requirement please answer asap..

Comment: are you able to copy it from command line..like hadoop fs -put  source   hdfs-dest

Comment: Ya from command line it is working fine, but whenever i am running using Java api it showing the error permission denied for the user

Comment: post your command ,is it with sudo or with out.  is your command like  sudo -u hdfs  hadoop fs -put...

Comment: Ya my command is without sudo only,i am running that command through root user like hadoop fs -put....

Comment: "sudo -u Srinivas.budida hadoop fs -put inptutPath  OutputPath"   try with this command in your command prompt .if you are not able to copy it. then try it  .."sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 Pathtohdfs". I am not understanding what the issue is..its working in my environment,.even its working with already created directory.  by the chmod command you can give the permission to folder with the user.

Comment: hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 Pathtohdfs this is working fine through command line, but i dont want to give the permissions through command line , i want to give the permissions to target directory using java api whenever moves the data into target directory is there any api for checking permissions of target directory.....